# Can't override __str__ method

Tags: python, printing, overriding

It's print a standart print

like [[2, 3, 7, 8, 10], [7, 6, 8, 9, 9], [9, 2, 12, 18, 9], [2, 3, 4, 5, 7]]

but i need

```
 1 1 4 4 5
 4 4 5 7 8
 2 3 9 8 8
```

my code

```
"""
Numeric Matrix Processor
author: Arturexp
"""


class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.matrix = array
        self.rows = len(array)
        self.columns = len(array[0])

    @property
    def shape(self):
        return self.rows, self.columns

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.matrix[item]

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join([" ".join(map(str, i)) for i in self.matrix])

    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join(['\t'.join([str(cell) for cell in row]) for row in self.matrix])

    def __add__(self, other):
        if self.shape != other.shape:
            return "ERROR"
        else:
            return [[self[i][j] + other[i][j] for j in range(self.columns)] for i in range(self.rows)]


def get_matrix_from_input():
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    return [list(map(int, input().split())) for list1 in range(a)]


matrix1 = Matrix(get_matrix_from_input())
matrix2 = Matrix(get_matrix_from_input())
result = matrix1 + matrix2

print(matrix1 + matrix2)
```

'''

Comment: `__add__` returns in one case, a `str`, `"ERROR"` (this should probably raise an exception, not return a magical string) *or* it returns a `list`. It does not a `Matrix` object.

Comment: thx. it work    ` def __add__(self, other):
        try:
            if self.shape != other.shape:
                raise MatrixShapeError
            else:
                return Matrix([[self[i][j] + other[i][j] for j in range(self.columns)] for i in range(self.rows)])
        except MatrixShapeError:
            print("ERROR")
            exit(0)`

Comment: Don't raise an error just to catch it like that. Just raise it.